# C++ reading file line by line

Tags: c++

There is a text file I want to display, but I only get the first line, not sure how to do this:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("myfile.txt");
getline(myfile, line); 
cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: Google "loop control structures in C++".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("myfile.txt");

   if(!myfile.is_open()) {
      perror("Error open");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
    while(getline(myfile, line)) {
     cout << line << endl;
    }
```

You just need to add a loop to get all lines of the file

Comment: Keep getting no such file or directory when it's there.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading line just once with one call of `getline(myfile, line);`
You need to do that in a loop until all lines are read.
[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)